# Are probabilities equivalent to a metric in phase space?

Tags: quantum-gravity, phase-space

Say $P(A)=|\Psi(A)|^2$ is the probability of event $A$.

So to add up many probabilities we would have: $\int P(A)dA$. But $P(A)$ looks like some sort of weight on the state $A$. This looks a lot like how we measure the volume of a surface: $\int \sqrt{g(x)} dx^3$.

Therefor in the phase/configuration space of all states, could the probability be viewed as the metric volume of that phase space? Because then we wouldn't need to assign a probability to each state, only look at the "shape" of the phase space. Viewing the phase space as a curved survace.

In this interpretation only the determinant of the metric of the phase space would seem important I can't see any point of the rest of it. (Or is there?)

Would this be a valid interpretation? It would mean that for any time, the total volume of the phase-space would be 1.

(I guess one problem might be if some of the values of $P(A)$ are singular.)

Comment: The integral $\int P(A) dA$ is a Lebesgue integral over some measure space. This means that indeed it is defined on some space. The integral for the volume of a surface $\int \sqrt{g(x)}d^3x$ however is defined over some differentiable manifold, not necessarily a measure space. The notions are therefore quite different, although I admit that they look similar. If you wish, you can think of $P(A)$ and $\sqrt{g(x)}$ as the probability density and volume density resp., so physically they play both the role of a density. Mathematically however, it is different

Comment: @Mathphys doesn't that mean the second encompasses the first? So that would mean my assumption is correct? Could you elabortate? If we said the "metric" of the phase space had to satisfy certain conditions?

Comment: Not every differentiable manifold has the 'right structure' to be a measure space. So the second does not imply the first and vice versa. Only in some special cases, this may be done. E.g. if you consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ then you can equip it with standard topology, smooth altas, Borel-sigma algebra and Lebesgue measure to have all structures. But generically not every set $M$ can be equipped with all of this